# Sqoop Error while using any sqoop command

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I am using hadoop 2.6.0,now i am trying sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha.tar.gz.I am getting sqoop version using

```
sqoop version
2016-10-19 16:11:21,722 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Sqoop@92] - Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5
Sqoop 1.4.5
```

but if i am trying any sqoop command it's giving the following exception,

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password hadoop


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addDeprecations([Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration$DeprecationDelta;)V
```

I copied mysql connector jar to sqoop/lib also.I am not able to find the cause.anybody have any idea please share me how to solve this.

Comment: Please make you are using the correct dependencies. Check the version of all dependecies

Comment: can you share the $SQOOP_CONF_DIR/sqoop-env.sh
and list $HADOOP_HOME

Comment: sqoop-env.sh                 export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/hbase
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export ZOOCFGDIR=/usr/local/zookeeper/conf                                     in .bashrc         export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/local/sqoop
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
export SQOOP_CONF_DIR=$SQOOP_HOME/conf
export SQOOP_CLASSPATH=$SQOOP_CONF_DIR
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$SQOOP_HOME/lib

Comment: in .bashrc                                                                                         export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export PATH=/usr/local/hadoop/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin

Comment: anybody have any idea about this help me.

Comment: type ls /usr/local/hadoop/ and copy the output

Comment: ls /usr/local/hadoop/                                                                                  bin  include  libexec      logs        README.txt  share
etc  lib      LICENSE.txt  NOTICE.txt  sbin

Comment: does your lib in /usr/local/hadoop/ path has hadoop-common.jar

Comment: yes i have hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar in /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126122/discussion-between-nirmal-ram-and-user6608138).

Comment: Thank you Nirmal Ram.you solved my problem.

Comment: @user6608138 you should post the solution for question above as it is resolved.

Comment: I copied hadoop 2.6.0, hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar file to sqoop/lib.and I copied hadoop/core-site.xml file of hadoop to sqoop/conf. After that sqoop is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

`sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename`

This is the correct query for listing all the tables in a particular database, the port number for mysql by default is **3306**.

Answer (score 1):

$ps -ef|grep -i manager

You can find whether node manager working or not

$ps -fu hdfs

It will show whether namenode datanode and secondary namenode working or not

$ps -fu yarn

It will show node manager and resource manager working or not

If all working in the sense sqoop will work..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user in MySQL

```
CREATE USER 'usrname'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'usrname'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Now you can run the query

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.18/mysql  --username 
usrname -P
```

Answer (score 0):

1. sqoop help // this will display all required commands
2. to display all data bases 
   sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/ --username root --password cloudera
3. to display all tables
   sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename --username root --password cloudera

Answer (score 0):

You should globalize sqoop path by adding into bashrc file. Steps given below.

1. Open terminal
2. Open. bashrc file

> sudo gedit ~/. bashrc

3. In it add sqoop home dir path as following.

> SQOOP_HOME = /absolute/path/of/sqoop
>
> PATH = $PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin

4. Then save it and close it. In terminal type.

> bash

5. Now try to run sqoop command.